# Calculating frequency of occurrences without hiding lines

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need some guidance regarding calculating frequency in a DataFrame.

Basically, I need to calculate the frequency of occurrences of a column, creating a new column with the percentage found, based on a simple condition of another column:

For example:

| index | Col1 | ... | Col9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | ... | 49 |
| 1 | a | ... | 51 |
| 2 | b | ... | 49 |
| 3 | b | ... | 49 |
| 4 | c | ... | 51 |
| 5 | c | ... | 49 |
| 6 | c | ... | 49 |
| 7 | c | ... | 51 |

I will add a new percentage column, where the condition would be, for example (Col9 > 50), based on the number of rows in Col1

| index | Col1 | ... | Col9 | Percentual |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | ... | 49 | 50% |
| 1 | a | ... | 51 | 50% |
| 2 | b | ... | 49 | 0% |
| 3 | b | ... | 49 | 0% |
| 4 | c | ... | 51 | 25% |
| 5 | c | ... | 49 | 25% |
| 6 | c | ... | 49 | 25% |
| 7 | c | ... | 49 | 25% |

- For occurrence "a" of Col1 (2 occurrences), we have 50% with Col9 > 50.
- For occurrence "b" of Col2 (2 occurrences), we have 0 with Col9 > 50.
- For occurrence "c" of Col3 (4 occurrences), we have 25% with Col9 > 50.

The difficulty is to mark all the lines of the dataframe, in the new percentage column, with the specific percentage of the rule. I want all the rows in their new percent column to inform me that there is X% of a certain grouping ("a" for example) that are within the rule.

Some grouping options reduce my dataframe in number of lines, as they count and hide, so as not to repeat the percentage display. But in my case I need all the rows and columns.

I need all columns, Percentage included.

```
df = df.sort_values(['index', 'Col1'], ascending = (True, True))
df = df.groupby(['index', 'Col1']['Col9'].apply(lambda x: (some rule like Col9 > 50).reset_index(name='Percentual')
```

My ordering of the DataFrame would be by 'index' and 'Col1'.
But I'm not able to retain all the lines, and indicate the percentage in the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

`assign` would do the job for you. It is important to set the "pivot" column as index first:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":["a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c"], "col9":[49, 51, 49, 49, 51, 49, 49, 49]})

grouping_index = ["col1"]
df = df.set_index(grouping_index)

df = df.assign(percentage=df.groupby(grouping_index)[["col9"]].agg(lambda x: sum(x>50)/len(x))).reset_index()
```